# Azure Event Grid to Azure Event Hub events delivery failed

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

We run into a problem with the subject.
May be someone knows a solution. Talking to Azure support for 4 days already and the only thing they come up is "it looks like a problem on your end".

Events are being published to Azure Event Grid endpoint. Event Grid has an Event Hubs as a subscriber. Most of the time everything works. But sometimes there are events "delivery failed".
Since it is critical for no events go missing, I'm trying to figure out how fix it.
But unfortunately diagnostics tools of Azure aren't really user friendly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNT7y.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQAPz.jpg)

Tried talking to Azure support with no success so far. Tried diagnostics tools - no success

Comment: It seems to me that these delivery failed errors, which are socket errors as it looks on metrics, happen around the same time during the day, am i correct? --- Socket error is defined as "Network communication error occurred during delivery.
"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry

Comment: I have a feeling there is a connection trouble from your source into event grid. Either your systems are busy, unable to provide connection to event grid, or something else. If you notice something in common with these errors, such as in the system publishing these events, maybe we will be able to find what is going on. Can you paste the whole error message?

Answer (score 0):

Those errors happen randomly during the day. They happen when EventGrid tries to deliver event to Azure Event Hub. There are no error related to publishing from my source to Azure Event Grid. Upon digging into the logs, I found "Internal error" when trying to deliver to Event Hub.